# Problems caused by Facebook like button changing to confirm in iframe application

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I've developed a Facebook iframe application, where we run a contest. It can be found here :
http://www.united-bakeries.no/facebook/tub/0412/

(The web site is in norwegian. The link will expire on March 4th when the contest ends.)

The contest is about guessing the winner of the Vasaloppet ski race. When you click the like button on one of the athletes, the pictures of all the athletes disappear, and a form appears where the athlete you liked is selected in a select box, and you are asked to submit your email address to take part in the contest. You can also reach this form without liking one of the athletes, by clicking the link below all the athletes where it says "Dersom du ønsker å delta i konkurransen uten å klikke Liker på en av deltakerne over klikk her.".

I think the contest works exactly in the same way as the Quiz application that Offerpop offers ( http://offerpop.com/SiteProduct.psp?view=quiz ).

This worked great for awhile. But after some time the Like button suddenly changed so that it now needs confirmation. This is apparently very confusing for users, as the statistics show that people stopped participating in the contest when the confirm button appeared. Offerpop doesn't seem to have the same problem with their applications. Why?

I have put an alert box there explaining to people that they need to press the confirm button for it to work, but it seems that it then becomes too complicated for most people.  Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: This problem seems to have solved itself for the moment, as the Confirm button is now gone from the application. However, I would still like information on how to avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmation link appears when facebook notices something suspicius about where the like button is placed and how it is shown to the user. That means if you are hiding any part of the button, if it is completely hidden under a custom button or if your links get too many unlikes.
Even for 'legit' likes you may get the confirmation button but it will soon dissapear if everything is right. If not, contact Facebook. 
Hope it helps.